# Python 3.8.0 xlwings save fails on windows 7

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying the following code:
which is failing on winodows 7 with Python 3.8.0
but running successfully on Windows 10 Python 3.8.0

```
import xlwings as xw
template = "template1.xlsx"

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(template)
ws = wb.sheets['warnings']
ws.range('A12').value = "This is a Test"
wb.save(r"D:\Polyspace\test.xlsx")
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

and I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    wb.save(r"D:\Polyspace\test.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1065, in save
    self.impl.save(path, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 829, in save
    self.xl.SaveAs(
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 95, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 46571, in SaveAs
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

if I do `wb.save()`, everything is fine. but if I want to save it to a new file is fails

I have already googled and tried all different solutions. mostly it was suggested to use a full path, but it still fails

Comment: Did you try to save to different folders? Maybe on Windows 7 the directory you are trying to write is protected in some way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a backslash not forward:

```
import xlwings as xw
template = "template1.xlsx"

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(template)
ws = wb.sheets['warnings']
ws.range('A12').value = "Peter"
wb.save(r'D:\Polyspace\test.xlsx')
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Comment: I updated my question. I am using back slash. but the same error

Comment: @user3122648 Did you try using single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `normpath` method from the `os.path` module. Your code would look something like this:

```
import xlwings as xw
import os

template = "template1.xlsx"

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(template)
ws = wb.sheets['warnings']
ws.range('A12').value = "This is a Test"

path = os.path.normpath(r'D:/Polyspace/test.xlsx')

wb.save(path)
wb.close()
app.quit()
```