# Unable to save Excel workbook file under the same name

Tags: python, xlwings

[Question related to unanswered: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72364144/python-3-8-0-xlwings-save-fails-on-windows-7/75775612#75775612](https://stackoverflow.com)]

I am using the Xlwings Python package to open an existing Excel file, write into it, close and save it using the **same** name (ie. overwriting the original file).

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import xlwings as xw

excel_file = "C:\\Working Drive\\Automation Scripts\\my_file.xlsx"
with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
    wb = app.books.open(excel_file)
    ws = wb.sheets['MySheet']
    # write into some cells...
    wb.save(excel_file)
    wb.close()
```

The Excel file opens as needed and the modifications are done inside it as per the code. I can even see the pop-up window appear from Excel saying "file saving" with the file path. Once the saving seems to be complete (ie. the progress bar on the excel pop up reaches the end), my code crashes and displays the following error at the wb.save() line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    wb.save(excel_file)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1147, in save
    self.impl.save(path, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 847, in save
    self.xl.SaveAs(
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 1-9, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 45271, in SaveAs
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-214735267, 'Exception Occured', (0, "Microsoft Excel", "Cannot access 'my_file.xlsx'.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I tried saving the same file, in the same directory under a **different** name and it works

wb.save("C:\Working Drive\Automation Scripts\my_file_1.xlsx")

I tried using `os.path.normpath()` on all paths, but problem still persists.

Comment: Try `wb.save()` without argument.

Comment: Throws another error pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft 
Excel', 'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, 
-2146827284), None)

Comment: If you haven't done so, I would restart  the PC to ensure there are no instances of the file open and locks on the file if they exist are freed.